# Unexpected token < for boostrap.js and chart.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, charts

i am trying to include `boostrap.min.js` for my hosting server but it gives me
**Unexpected token <**... but when i use bootstrap `CDN` it worked. I thought this wasn't going to trouble me any further until i started using `Angular-Chart.js`. I get the same issue again.

Ok here my include structure:

```
<link href="app/views/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="app/views/css/myStyle.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="app/views/css/angular-chart.css">

<script src="app/views/js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"> </script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.15/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0rc1/angular-route.min.js"></script>

<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<!-- Services -->
<script src="app/services/authService.js"></script>
<script src="app/services/userService.js"></script>
<script src="app/services/storyService.js"></script>
 <!--Controller -->
<script src="app/controller/mainController.js"></script>
<script src="app/controller/storyCtrl.js"></script>
<script src="app/controller/userCtrl.js"></script>

<!--Directives -->
<script src="app/directives/reverse.js"></script>
<script src="app/app.routes.js"></script> 
<script src="app/app.js"></script>

**Contents**

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="app/views/js/angular-chart.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Open the network tab in the console, inspect the result of the bootstrap.min.js. I suspect it to be an html error page.

Comment: wouldn't be surprised if this throws it off too - `/socket.io/socket.io.js`

Comment: yeah is a html error page.... it starts from <!DOCTYPE html> mguimard.
What i am suppose to look for in network tab as i never use that before

Answer (score 0):

AngularJs throws that error when you have a missing resources. Check if all your scripts/styles in the head tag are actually found. And check if you have no missing style. Actually i think your third style should be:

```
<link href="app/views/css/angular-chart.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

That can probably fix it. I had a script with source `"#"` and I got that same error.
 And according to 
[This link to the issue on Github](https://github.com/fnakstad/angular-client-side-auth/issues/67) , installing bower fixes the problem most of the time.

> Yeah, this is a typical problem when one of your resources defined in
>   the index.html file is missing.
>
> If you check the console.log in your server terminal, you might be
>   able to figure out which one is missing. The missing one should have a
>   404 status code, while all the other ones are either 200 or 304
>   (cached).

Comment: Dam that didnt fix it, unfortunately.

Comment: edited my answer. do you have any 404 missing resources problem when looking in your console ? because if it clearly works with the cdn then it is probably not finding it on your server

Comment: Sorry for not being throughout with my words. but i am fetching boostrap from my localhost, and i am not getting 404 error.

Comment: okay so 404 isn't the problem, try installing bower. Did you try that?